# Query to fetch minimum date with condition

Tags: sql, impala

```
   create table t(dt1 date,dt2 date,dt3 date,dt4 date)

    insert into t values('1970-01-01','2008-10-10',NULL,NULL),
(NULL,'2008-10-10','2017-10-12',NULL),('1970-01-01','2008-10-10',NULL,'2018-10-09')
```

I have code this query

```
select *, (select min(dates) 
           from (values (dt1), (dt2), (dt3), (dt4))a(dates)
           where a.dates > '1970-01-01') as DDt
from t;
```

but its not working on impala and giving below error-

`^ encountered Exception syntax error`

Comment: hmm works ok in sql server...

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
select *, (select min(dt1) 
           from (select dt1 from t union select dt2 from t union select dt3 from t union select dt4 from t)a
           where a.dt1 > '1970-01-01') as DDt
from t
```

Comment: I get this `Error: sub queries are not supported in the select list` :(

Comment: Wow impala is pretty awful! What functionality do you have? Can you create temp tables etc?

Comment: I am pretty to impala :( I am exploring the docs, but there isn't much mentioned